# Public and internal paths on the same domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

There's a domain `api.example.com`. I want the requests to `api.example.com/internal/*` to be routed to an internal API Gateway or an internal Load Balancer, and the rest of the requests to be routed to a public API Gateway.

By internal I mean non-internet facing, i.e. in private VPC subnets. The requests to these internal routes will be coming from the same VPC.

Is it possible to do it with an AWS service and avoid custom solutions?

Comment: Creating an A record in route53 for the specific request and then a catch all should do this for you.

Comment: @ASimpleProgrammer could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with multiple origins in an AWS CloudFront distribution.

Comment: I tried that, CloudFront returns 502 (couldn't connect to the origin) for the private routes. It makes sense to me, CloudFront distribution isn't inside my VPC.

Comment: I thought you just meant "private" as in "behind a login" or something. If that content can only be accessed from inside the VPC, then I'm confused about what you are even trying to do. Is everything that needs to access the `/private` path also running in the same VPC?

Comment: Yes. I was using 'private' as in private subnets. A better word is probably 'internal'.  I've edited my question. A team of developers wants a single service with both public and internal routes. This way they want to eliminate a layer of security concerns. We'll probably have to go with 2 domains.

Comment: A separate subdomain for the private services is MUCH more common, and much easier to manage and secure as well.